# Create an image with text over filling space

Tags: imagemagick

I want to create a flare image using imagemagick and then add text on top of it.  I was thinking that it was going to be quite easy, but I am having issues adding the text on top of the generated image.

This is so far what I have (keep in mind that the text as well as the dimension are dynamic):

FLARE:

```
\(
-fill transparent -size 300x1 xc: +noise Random -channel G -separate +channel \
-scale 300x300\! \
\( -size 300x300 gradient: -evaluate cos .5 \) \
-compose hardlight -composite \
-virtual-pixel HorizontalTileEdge -distort Polar -1
\)
```

TEXT

```
-fill red \
-gravity center \
-font Arial \
annotate:"Logo 12345678"
```

**EDIT:**
The text is showing, but I can't figure out how to overimpress the text on top of the image in a way that it will fill the image for the full width (from left to right, with some padding if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out:

```
convert \
\( -background transparent -size 300x1 xc: +noise Random -channel G -separate +channel -scale 300x300\! \( -size 300x300 gradient: -evaluate cos .5 \) -compose hardlight -composite -virtual-pixel HorizontalTileEdge -distort Polar -1 \) \
\( -background transparent -size 300x300 -fill blue -gravity center -font Arial caption:"Logo \\n13474899" \) \
-gravity center -composite /tmp/flare_2_final.png
```

Now I need to figure out how to change the background color of the flare from black to gray and I am done.

Comment: But the background color isn't black, or? It's transparent, and the flare is mostly grayscale...

Comment: I was able to fix it by adding the gradient with a different cos